# JSON-LD product page markup for multiple currencies?

Tags: seo, json-ld

I was wondering if there is a working example of a product page with multiple "priceCurrency" and "price". If we have two regions and prices for them and one domain is it possible to structure json-ld to have both prices and currencies? Something like this:

```html
"offers": {
  "@type": "Offer",
  "priceCurrency": "GBP",
  "price": "219.95",
  "availability": "https://schema.org/InStock"
},
"offers": {
  "@type": "Offer",
  "priceCurrency": "EUR",
  "price": "200",
  "availability": "https://schema.org/InStock"
},
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that by declaring multiple offers using an array. This is your modified example:

```
"offers": [
    {
        "@type": "Offer",
        "priceCurrency": "GBP",
        "price": "219.95",
        "availability": "https://schema.org/InStock"
    },
    {
        "@type": "Offer",
        "priceCurrency": "EUR",
        "price": "200",
        "availability": "https://schema.org/InStock"
    }
]
```

Comment: Do offers need `eligibleRegion` or `areaServed` to specify where they apply? Or location is inferred from currency?

Comment: If you can provide such data, it is always a good idea, but Google doesn't require those properties.